# Send an Email as the Currently Logged in User | Google API

Tags: api, email

Is it possible to send an email to join the site as the currently logged in user on your site to his/her contacts?

Comment: That sounds like sending an email under false pretences,

Comment: @pavium: Not necessarily - e.g. sharing a page link through e-mail (yes, yes, I know e-mail is not cool, only old people use e-mail, Foo Bar is the new e-mail and all that).

Comment: Ok, I see it might be acceptable to *cool* types. It's like they say at 'The Onion' - Facebook was created by the CIA to save a lot of effort collecting information about people.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that now with the [GMail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/). You will need the user's consent of course, and will need the Contacts API to retrieve the user's contacts.